# Fitting a string in a textview

Tags: android, textview, font-size

I have a textview of width `maxWidth`. I am using following function to choose font size of a string to fit in the textview. The function returns fontsize such that the width of the string matches the textview width. However the textview shows only part of the string . What is wrong ?

```
private int determineMaxTextSize(String str, float maxWidth)
{
    int size = 0;       
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    do {
        paint.setTextSize(++ size);
    } while(paint.measureText(str) < maxWidth);



    Log.d("wop",""+paint.measureText(str));
    return size;
}
```

This is how the string is displayed.

```
LayoutParams params;
params = textview.getLayoutParams();
params.height = maxWidth;
params.width=maxWidth;
textview.setLayoutParams(params);
int textsize=determineMaxTextSize("60 s", maxWidth);
textview.setTextSize(textsize);
textview.setText("60 s");
```

This is the outcome.

[image]

Comment: How are you using the value that is returned from `determineMaxTextSize()`?

Comment: edited the question to explain how the text is being displayed.

Comment: @erakitin that did not work\

Comment: You might consider just using an existing component for this, like https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview or https://github.com/danclarke/AutoResizeTextView.

Comment: @user3293494 attach a screenshot please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Paint#measureText()` returns value in `dip`. Need to convert it to pixels.

Try this code:

```
private int determineMaxTextSize(String str, float maxWidth) {
    int size = 0;
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    float scaleDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    do {
        paint.setTextSize(++ size);
    } while (paint.measureText(str) * scaleDensity < maxWidth);

    return --size;
}
```